# Printing a PDF enters a long and slow flattening process

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I am programmatically trying to create an pdf by superimposing two pdf files using itextpdf. The PDF that was made goes into this flattening process for some reason, how do I skip flattening or make the process faster.

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(template);
PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream(dest));

PdfReader r;
PdfImportedPage page;
int i=1;
for (String path : patterns) {
    r = new PdfReader(path);
    for(int j=1;j<=r.getNumberOfPages();j++) {
        page = stamper.getImportedPage(r, j);
        PdfContentByte canvas = stamper.getUnderContent(i++);
        canvas.addTemplate(page, 0, 0);
        stamper.getWriter().freeReader(r);
    }
    r.close();
}
stamper.close();
```

Comment: You write "The PDF that was made goes into this flattening process for some reason." If you want to know the reason, please show us your code.

Comment: All interactivity that was previously present in `template` will be gone; all the interactivity that was previously present in the `path` files, should be preserved. There is a strange quirk in your code that I don't understand, but that might be intentional: why is `i` different from `j`? Also: you are using an old version of iText that is no longer supported: the `PdfStamper` class no longer exists in iText 7. Stamping is done differently now.

Comment: Please upgrade you code to a [mcve].

Comment: @Bruno *"why is `i` different from `j`?"* - They coincide for the first `path` in `patterns` and are different later.

Comment: @mkl So I see, but what if the sum of the pages of all the files in `patterns` is bigger than the total number of pages in `template`? Wouldn't that throw an exception?

Comment: It should indeed. Yes, the code needs hardening,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The PDF that was generated from Adobe Illustrator had an masked image instead of a proper component. I am sorry if the answer seems vague but I am not a designer but the flattening process happens when the one or more of the original PDFs that are being merged aren't proper.